# GDB remote debugging

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging

I managed to set up a gdbserver for a [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) application and ran it on a 64-bit Ubuntu computer using:

```
gdbserver <ip>:20000 ./sampleQtApp
```

And I tried to connect it to using a remote computer of the same network using GDB as follows:

```
set architecture i386:x86-64:intel
target remote <ip>:20000
```

It gives me the following output, and I can not figure out why.

```
(gdb) target remote 10.9.5.79:20000
warning: A handler for the OS ABI "GNU/Linux" is not built into this configuration
of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default i386:x86-64 settings.

Remote debugging using 10.9.5.79:20000
Remote register badly formatted:      T0506:0000000000000000;07:a080c7ceff7f0000;10:f0fae7b0107f0000;thread:7c0;core:0;
here: 00000000;07:a080c7ceff7f0000;10:f0fae7b0107f0000;thread:7c0;core:0;
(gdb)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What is your gdb/gdbserver version? Try a more recent one. Look also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3073394/72178) question.