# How to set an arbitrary 64 bits of memory in GDB

Tags: gdb

I'm learning to use GDB on my own (for the purpose of understanding an assignment that requires binary analysis) and need a little bit of help. I've looked through the manual but can't find an answer to this specific issue.

I know where a 64-bit pointer resides in memory, and I want to change the address that it points to. When I try to set the value of the memory address, it only seems to modify the last 32 bits instead of the entire 64 bits.

```
(gdb) x/xg $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe338: 0x0000000000400a2d
(gdb) set *0x7fffffffe338 = 0x7fffffffe130
(gdb) x/xg $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe338: 0x00000000ffffe130
```

What's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you always can do `call memset()`;

Comment: Is it your gdb set it in 64 bit mod, you may get some hints from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073394/using-gdb-and-gdbserver-with-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-machine-with-centos-5-c

Comment: I'm using 64-bit GDB and the executable I'm debugging is 64-bit. I'm also on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Try `set *(int64_t *)0x7fffffffe338 = 0x7fffffffe130` or, more apt in your case, `set *(char **)0x7fffffffe338 = 0x7fffffffe130`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks! This worked for me. Can you explain why it doesn't work without the cast?

Comment: `(gdb) whatis *0x7fffffffe338` returns `int`, and that's 32 bits wide on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Workaround:**

I was able to work around this issue by setting 32 bits at a time rather than all 64 bits at once:

```
(gdb) x/xg $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe548: 0x0000000000400a2d

#little-endian
(gdb) set *0x7fffffffe548 = 0xffffe130
(gdb) set *0x7fffffffe54c = 0x00007fff

(gdb) x/2xw $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe548: 0xffffe130      0x00007fff
(gdb) x/xg $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe548: 0x00007fffffffe130
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @MarkPlotnick in the comments, the reason and correct method of assignment for this is:

`(gdb) whatis *0x7fffffffe338` returns `int`, which is 32-bits wide on x86_64.

Casting to int64_t or char** will force GDB to set all 64-bits of memory in the assignment:

`set *(int64_t *)0x7fffffffe338 = 0x7fffffffe130`
or
`set *(char **)0x7fffffffe338 = 0x7fffffffe130`
results in

```
(gdb) x/xg $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe548: 0x00007fffffffe130
```